# Select Query from two tables in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, model, html-table

I have 2 tables:
Events and Registration.

Events Fields:  EventID and EventName

Registration Field:  MemberID and Name

I want to pull the EventName and the Name- of the person. How do I do this with a model?
The code I have: 

**Model**

```
function getAll()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('tblRegistration');
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $query->free_result();
    return $data;
}
```

**controller**

```
public function getallevents() {
    $this->load->model('events_model');

    $data['records'] = $this->events_model->getAll();

    $this->load->view('view-events', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
              foreach ($records as $row):
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td> $row->Name</td>";
                        // echo "<td> $row->intLocationID</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    endforeach;
```

**Edit**

OK I have added the data that I want out of the table.

**model**

```
   function getAll()
{
    // get all the records from the schools table

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tblRegistration as reg');
    $this->db->join('tblMeetRace as met', 'reg.intMeetRaceID = met.intEventID');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    // if the number of rows returned is more than 0
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0) {
        // loop through each record (row) and place that
        // record into an array called $data
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $query->free_result();
    // return the array to the controller
    return $data;
}
```

**view**

```
     foreach ($records as $row):
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td> $row->intMeetRaceID/td>";
                        echo "<td> $row->intEventID</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    endforeach;
```

but I get an error of:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>   Filename: views/view-events.php
>   Line Number: 89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to add another column in your events table for storing the `MemberId`, say `memberid`. 
Once you have that, when ever a member registers for an event, you can store his `ID` in the events table and relate it.

Then you can use `Joins` to fetch the datas

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('registration as reg');
$this->db->join('events as evt', 'reg.id = evt.memberid');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay so do i have to put things in the select('*') or the get()? or dose that select everything?

Comment: It selects everything

Comment: if you can look at the edit i have made now i am getting this error

Comment: Thats because I think the result is empty. try printing the result and see what you get. Also try $this->db->last_query(), this prints the latest query that has run, check whether that is the desired query which you wanted to run